# Online math contests

Tags: contest-math

I know from my friends who major in CS that there are many reputable online CS constests.

Can you give me examples of reputable online math contests ?

It would be better if they are for undergraduates.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just by hanging around here I have learned about [Brilliant.org](http://brilliant.org/). I should let @CalvinLin advertise that site properly in his (coming?) answer, as he is involved with them.

Comment: [Al Zimmermann's Programming Contests](http://www.azspcs.net/)

Answer (score 8):

http://www.brilliant.org has weekly problem sets at five different levels in Algebra, Number Theory, and Combinatorics

http://www.internetolympiad.org has monthly contests with prizes, in addition to seasonal team proof-based contests (One called the Winter NIMO, and the others part of the Online Math Open)

http://www.proofathon.org/ is a monthly competition where each competition is themed on a different topic (the ongoing contest is themed "Graph Theory and Game Theory")

MathFights: http://www.mathfights.com is a real-time math game at levels ranging from easy MATHCOUNTS problems to high AMC12-level problems.

For The Win: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Edutainment/ftwcs3/index.php is a real-time math game meant to simulate the MATHCOUNTS Countdown Round

Comment: Some more there?

Answer (score 1):

http://purplecomet.org conducts team based competitions,run by Awesome Math Summer Program.

Comment: [Ponder This  : Monthly puzzle from IBM Research](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/index.shtml) They publish the correct answer in the next month and also the name of first person who sent the correct answer.